# Using android sql lite database

Tags: android

Good day!

I have 1000 list of items that I want to add in the SQL Database in Android.

900 of the items is already be existing and I need to store it because it can be edited.
100 of these will be added by the user using CRUD.

How can I input the 900 items and do it only once?
I am planning to create outside the database first then just add it on the android.

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) but upon creating the table, i don't know how i can input the 900 items.

I am planning to create outside the database first then just add it on the android and just use that database (e.g. where should i put the database? how can i call it using the java code). But how can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are going to need to ask a specific question that can be answered with code.

Comment: simple, use the keyboard, or script it into sqlite....?

Comment: Sorry do you want to add a preexisting dB file to your apk on first runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the database outside of Android then you can create a text file with the SQL needed to add the records e.g.

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> VALUES (<_id value>,<field value>, etc etc);
```

name it foo.sql and then from the SQLite prompt

```
sqlite> .read foo.sql
```

If the db already exists in SQLite you can re-create the SQL statements by

```
sqlite> .dump <tablename>
```

This will create the sql statments to both create the table and do the INSERTS

Answer (score 1):

Just use insert with an array of content values passed into your sqlite class then update shared preferences. Alternatively you can do the same but passing in an array list and using the execute command. or even more alternatively you can put it in the on create which will only be called once.